# What does it mean "getavg must return value" in this program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am in an introductory programming class and am having problems solving a problem. It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help.

The program should display the average number of pounds of coffee ordered. The number of pounds ordered are stored in the pounds array. Complete the program using the while statement.

```
//Introductory22.cpp - displays the average number of pounds ordered
//Created/revised by <your name> on <current date>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//function prototype
double getAvg();

int main()
{
   double pounds[6] = {10, 15.5, 17, 18.5, 11, 12.5};
   double average = 0.0;

   average = getAvg();
   cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
   cout << "Average number of pounds ordered: " << average << endl;
   return 0;
}   //end of main function

//*****function definitions*****
void getAvg()
{
   int x = 0;
   do // begin loop
   {
      cout << pounds[6] << endl;
      x += 1 pounds[sub];
   } while (x < 6);
   return static_cast<double>(total) / numElements;
}   //end of getAvg function
```

That is my code and I get error C4716 - getavg must return a value.

What simple way could I fix this?

Comment: Look at the return type of `getAvg()` in the prototype and in the definition. See anything wrong?

Comment: BTW, even after fixing the code according to the suggested answer, `pounds` is undefined in `getAvg()`, and `x += 1 pounds[sub];` is a syntax error in addition to `sub` also being undefined. And `cout << pounds[6]` is undefined behaviour, and ...

Comment: The obscure code you have there isn't very useful. The English part of the error message actually tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration and function definitions have different signatures. You need to change your definition to return a double.